# Import and parse specific data from CSV-file by using PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, parsing, import-csv

Hello all and best wishes for 2022!

I have the following CSV file:

```
Name,EmployeeID,File
JohnDoechebox,0009001,ImageBig1.png
JohnDoechebox,0009001,ImageBig2.png
JohnDoechebox,0009001,ImageFlat1.jpg
JohnDoechebox,0009001,ImageFlat2.jpg
JaneJefferson,0009006,IntDoc.docx
JaneJefferson,0009006,IntDoc2.docx
JaneJefferson,0009006,IntImage.jpg
JaneJefferson,0009006,ExtImage.jpg
```

I want to import the CSV file, this I can do with `Import-CSV`. Then I want to `foreach` the imported CSV file so that all rows get parsed.

I have been testing a bit and I came up with the following:

```
$Name = @()
$EmployeeID = @()

# Importing the CSV file and fill the array

Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\TestNew.csv" |`
    ForEach-Object {
        $Name += $_."Name"
        $EmployeeID += $_."EmployeeID"

    Write-Host "Your name is $($_.Name) and your Employee ID is $($_.EmployeeID)"

    }
```

This works as expected. So now I want to build it so that I can get all the files for that specific user based on the EmployeeID (because names can be duplicate, EmployeeID is always unique) and output the files by `Write-Host`. Like this:

`Write-Host "Your name is $($_.Name) and your Employee ID is $($_.EmployeeID)" You have the following files:`

Later I also want to execute an action with each file to copy it somewhere.

Any help would be greatly apreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cool guys, thanks so much! This seems to do the job well:

`
$List = Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\TestNew.csv' | Group-Object EmployeeID

foreach ($User in $List) {

Write-Host "Your name is $($User.Group.Name[0]) and your Employee ID is $($User.Name) , You have the following files:"

$User.Group.File

}
`
What I don't understand is: Why does the `$($User.Name)` outputs the EmployeeID? 
I have made some changes to also create a folder based on the "Name" column and copy the files of the user (by using the EmployeeID) to that specific folder.

Comment: Sorry my markup in the comment is broken, idk why

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as follow

```
$list = import-csv 'C:\Temp\TestNew.csv' | Group-Object EmployeeID
foreach ($user in $list){

Write-Host "Your name is $($user.group.name[0]) and your Employee ID is $($user.Name) , You have the following files:"

$user.Group.file

}
```

Comment: Cool guys, thanks so much! This seems to do the job well:

    $List = Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\TestNew.csv' | Group-Object EmployeeID foreach ($User 
    in $List) { Write-Host "Your name is $($User.Group.Name[0]) and your Employee ID is 
    $($User.Name) , You have the following files:" $User.Group.File }

What I don't understand is: 

Why does the $($User.Name) outputs the EmployeeID? 

I have made some changes to also create a folder based on the "Name" column and copy the files of the user (by using the EmployeeID) to that specific folder.

Comment: The proper way to thank someone for helpful answers is to upvote it and/or mark as solution.

Comment: in order to know `Why does the $($User.Name) outputs the EmployeeID?`  you need to see the value of the variable `$list` , as we grouped the output based on the property `Name` employeeid

Comment: @Doug Maurer, thanks for comment

Answer (score 1):

To get all files with a specific `EmployeeID` value, use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to group the entries from the CSV by that specific column:

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\TestNew.csv" |Group-Object EmployeeID |ForEach-Object {
    # Get the whole list of file names
    $groupOfFileNames = $_.Group |ForEach-Object File
    # Pick the name from the first entry in the grouped list
    $userName = $_.Group[0].Name

    Write-Host "Your name is $($_.Name) and your Employee ID is $($_.EmployeeID)" 
    Write-Host "You have the following files: [$($groupOfFileNames -join ', ')]"
}
```